How to test my Nginx Location block for my wordpress multisite?
I am working on an nginx for wordpress multisite. Here I came to know the location blocks needs to be added for multisite nginx configuration(link) I need to test this below location block can anyone help me on this ?
location ~ ^(/[^/]+)?/files/(.+) { try_files /wp-content/blogs.dir/$blogid/files/$2 /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 ; access_log off;      log_not_found off;  expires max; }
I need to test this below location block can anyone help me on this ? I just need to understand in which scenario it is working on these two try file structure.
